# Can a specific branch or commit be used in the Source-Url for an OpenShift Cartridge?

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I'm using [this iojs OpenShift cartridge](https://github.com/connyay/openshift-iojs), which has now been updated to iojs 3.0, but I need a iojs 2.x version to test some functionality.

Looking at the cartridge's `manifest.yml` ([here](https://github.com/connyay/openshift-iojs/blob/master/metadata/manifest.yml)), I see the `Source-Url` set to the git repo (https://github.com/connyay/openshift-iojs.git). I was thinking if I change that to use an older version of the same Github repo, then I would get the older cartridge.

So does the `Source-Url` attribute support specifying branch or commit hashes (ala https://github.com/connyay/openshift-iojs.git#v2.5.0 etc) ? [The OpenShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#source-url) doesn't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to doesn't mention this directly, but it hinted at the solution in the example: `Source-Url: https://github.com/example/killer-cartridge/archive/master.zip`

So, for a specific branch, commit, or tag (respectively):

```
Source-Url: https://github.com/connyay/openshift-iojs/archive/master.zip
Source-Url: https://github.com/connyay/openshift-iojs/archive/ebd98692265f58c3f207555045a7c1a5ddb381a8.zip
Source-Url: https://github.com/luciddreamz/openshift-php/archive/v1.zip
```

The [OpenShift Cartridge reflector](https://github.com/smarterclayton/cartridge-reflector), for cartridges that do not specify a `Source-Url`, allows you to do this by [specifying a branch, commit, or tag in the 'commit' query parameter](https://developers.openshift.com/en/get-involved-extend-openshift.html#the-cartridge-reflector).